# bitwise operation, 0 -> 1, otherwise number

Tags: bit-manipulation

I need bitwise operation to get this result:

```
000 -> 001
001 -> 001
010 -> 010
011 -> 011
100 -> 100
...
```

basically it returns 1 when zero provided, otherwise it does not change anything about the input. Any ideas?

Comment: It's possible, but the only way I know is boring and inefficient relative to the task. What's your goal with this, do you care about it being useful at all?

Comment: `x = (x / 10 == 0) ? 1 : (x/10)` see I have to compute `x/10` twice. I was wondering whether there is a smart bit manipulation to make it more efficient

Comment: Well you could write `x /= 10; x = x == 0 ? 1 : x;` or some variation of that, right? Also, compilers often do common sub-expression elimination anyway, you can check the assembly code to verify that

Comment: `x = (x / 10 == 0) ? 1 : (x/10)` does not match the expected result. `x = (x / 10 == 0) ? 1 :  x` or `x = x & 0b110 ? 1 : x` would

Comment: I would say it does. Keeping in mind `x/10` gets floored down to an integer. Let's simplify this thing. Call `y = x/10`, then `x = (y == 0) ? 1 : y`

Comment: 010 / 10 is not 010 so how can `x = (x / 10 == 0) ? 1 : (x/10)` give the expected result?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't think that expression was meant as an implementation of the title of this question. It's the context in which the question is asked, the "set to 1 if 0" is only a part of it.

Comment: @harold Ok, but OP said _"see I have to compute x/10 twice. "_

Comment: Do you mean 'divide by ten' or 'divide by two'?  If the latter, you know that's just a shift, right?  But why do even that?  You have asked for `x==0 ? 1 : x`.  Your definition of what you want includes a conditional; you can't avoid it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo look to me as if `x / 10` occurs twice in that expression yes, what do you mean

Comment: @Arfur What I mean is "perform any weird and sophisticated operation", which results in a series of bits. And then return 0 if that series is 1, otherwise do not change anything

Comment: @harold I mean that the expression OP showed does not give the expected result and to get the expected result, doing `x / 10` twice isn't needed.

Comment: Just use `x == 0 ? 1 : x`.  Why is that not acceptable?  It is a straightforward expression of your stated requirement: *it returns 1 when zero provided, otherwise it does not change anything about the input*

Comment: @TedLyngmo it gives the expected result by definition

Comment: `y = computationally_intensive_operation(x) == 0 ? 1 : computationally_intensive_operation(x)` I dunno about that. And if I do this `y = computationally_intensive_operation(x); y = y==0 ? 1 : y` in this case `y` cannot be declared constant, which I would prefer very much.. sigh

Comment: I see nothing in the question that requires division by ten or two.  I see nothing in the question that  requires reassignment of the value back to `x`.

Comment: If you use two variables, they can both be const. Or you can put this make-it-1-if-it-was-0 thing in a function, and write `y = makeItNotZero(foo(x))` or whatever.

Comment: @ArfurNarf it's just an example of a situation where a solution to the question might be used, not the solution itself.

Comment: @harold - then it's no different in principle to worrying about repetition in `somefunc(x/10, x/10)` where parameters are passed by value - you avoid that by using auxiliary variables. Or hope the compiler can improve it.  (Thanks for the clarification, though)

Comment: Trying to do it with *bitwise* operations seems like a mistake.  A machine with conditional move instructions (including x86, arm, arm64) can compute `(x == 0) ? 1 : x` with just a couple of fast instructions and no branching. https://godbolt.org/z/4s5sKqP18  Any approach using bitwise operations is likely to be a lot less efficient.  As mentioned by harold you can DRY by making `(x == 0) ? 1 : x` into an inline function.

Comment: `const auto y = [&x]{ auto tmp = computationally_intensive_operation(x); return tmp==0 ? 1 : tmp; }()` would allow for `y` to be declared `const`

Answer (score 2):

The ultimate objective of the asker is not clear. It is also not clear what is included or excluded from "bitwise operations".

If the objective is the avoidance of conditional branches to avoid potential runtime variability (of concern in some crypto applications), the obvious choice of using the ternary operator in languages of the C family may not be suitable on some architectures. For example, from playing with [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/c13a8TWj6) it seems that use of the ternary operator can easily result in branch-y code with RISC-V.

Below I am showing four potential alternatives that implement the clamping requested by asker. Which of these is most suitable will depend on the processor architecture and the toolchain used and will need to be evaluated in the context of a specific use case. On modern(-ized) architectures like ARM64 and x86-64 using current releases of clang and gcc all four variants will generate quite similar code.

A note on `clamp_neg_carry()`: This is a C emulation of a classical *in-place* x86 clamping idiom: `neg mreg; adc mreg,-1; neg mreg`. In-place operation was valued due to the severe dearth of registers in the original x86 architecture. While it looks complicated, on various modern architectures with current toolchains this will generate branchless code that is equivalent to `clamp_bool_add()`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define VARIANT (3)

unsigned int clamp_ternary (unsigned int x)
{
    return (x == 0) ? 1 : x;
}

unsigned int clamp_cond_inc (unsigned int x)
{
    return (x == 0) ? (x + 1) : x;
}

unsigned int clamp_bool_add (unsigned int x)
{
    return x + (x == 0);
}

#define SUBcc(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b), t1=(a), cy=t1<t0, t1-t0)
#define ADDC(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b)+cy, t1=(a), t0+t1)
unsigned int clamp_neg_carry (unsigned int x)
{
    unsigned int cy, t0, t1;
    x = SUBcc (0,x,cy,t0,t1);
    x = ADDC (x,-1,cy,t0,t1); 
    x = 0 - x;
    return x;
}

int main (void)
{
    unsigned int x = 0;
    do {
        unsigned int ref = clamp_ternary (x);
#if VARIANT == 1
        unsigned int res = clamp_cond_inc (x);
#elif VARIANT == 2
        unsigned int res = clamp_bool_add (x);
#elif VARIANT == 3
        unsigned int res = clamp_neg_carry (x);
#else
#error unsupported VARIANT
#endif // VARIANT
        if (res != ref) {
            printf ("x=%08x ref=%08x res=%08x\n", x, ref, res);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        x++;
    } while (x);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If arithmetic operations are allowed, then this would work:

```
unsigned f(unsigned x) {
    return x | (((x >> 1) - 1) >> 31);
}
```